# "Hey! Over here!" challenge: where is the hidden claptrap located?

Tags: borderlands-2

I can't find the nasty "hidden claptrap" for this challenge found under the "Arid Nexus - Badlands" section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map location and how to get there in this video: